# How to start jenkins in a batch file (.bat)?

Tags: jenkins

I want to start jenkins.war file in a batch file. Basically I want a shortcut on my desktop to start it instead of opening cmd and typing in the commands.

Environment: Windows 10

Comment: A batch file is just a list of commands in a text file with the `.cmd` filename extension. So what's stopping you?.

Comment: I have already posted the answer. I have shared this as I was making a couple of mistakes like using start jenkin.war but because it is  a service you need to start it with java -jar

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Notepad
2. Type in the following code:

   `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins"`

   `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8082`
3. Save the file as a jenkins.bat file
4. Double click on jenkins.bat file, CMD should open and you should see that jenkins is starting

Comment: The bat file won't run when I double click it and there is no window. But, when I run the bat file as administrator, then it works. Do you know why ?